Displaying the user's data on the Flutter app from Firebase Authentication
I am building a simple chat application where in on the click of a button, I want to be able to see a list of all the authenticated users from my Firebase auth, how can I do the same?
I found solutions wherein the users were being fetched from the firestore collections although that's not what I'm looking at...

I'm looking to extract this data into lets say a list to display it in some way...How can I get this done?
